# multiple object of widgets run only one time initState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class CustomImageRectangle extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const CustomImageRectangle({Key key, this.url}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomImageRectangleState createState() => _CustomImageRectangleState();
}

class _CustomImageRectangleState extends State<CustomImageRectangle> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.url != null?'not null':'null');
  }
```

Above class, I called 3 times in my home widget, but only one-time run `initState`. why is that?

only 1 print in the console.

```
logo != ''
    ? FutureBuilder<String>(
         future: storage.getVendorLogo(logo),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     return CustomImageRectangle(url: snapshot.data);
                  } else {
                     return CustomImageRectangle();
                  }
             })
    : CustomImageRectangle(),
```

Comment: sorry for my bad Engilish. I think you can understand it

Comment: what is the value of  `logo` variable? Can you include that in the question details?

Comment: `logo` is coming from another api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomImageRectangle` isn't being created 3 times at once. It is being conditionally rendered once. Hence only once print is observed.

In the code snippet :

```
logo != ''
    ? FutureBuilder<String>(
         future: storage.getVendorLogo(logo),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     return CustomImageRectangle(url: snapshot.data);
                  } else {
                     return CustomImageRectangle();
                  }
             })
    : CustomImageRectangle(),
```

The `FutureBuilder` will only be returned if `logo!=''` is `true`.
In the `builder` of `FutureBuilder`, either  `if (snapshot.hasData)` will be `true` or `false`.

Depending on that only one of the `CustomImageRectangle(url: snapshot.data)` or `CustomImageRectangle()` will be returned.

Otherwise if `logo!=''` is `false` the  `CustomImageRectangle()` in the ternary operator will be returned.

Here `CustomImageRectangle` is created only once in all cases. Hence only once the `initState` is called.

Consider the below example where it is rendered 3 times at once:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomImageRectangle(),
            CustomImageRectangle(),
            CustomImageRectangle(),
          ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Console Output:

```
null
null
null
```

Comment: please add inside `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @BloodLoss sorry i did not understand why inside `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: inside `column` it's working. my problem is on `FutureBuilder`. you can check my code

Comment: @BloodLoss added explanation with respect to the original `FutureBuilder` snippet. The entire code block is conditional meaning that at a given time only one instance of `CustomImageRectangle` will be created depending on the truth value of condition. There won't be any possibility that all 3 of `CustomImageRectangle` will be called at once because the conditional execution.